# I am not able to capture image in window form application using c# code

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a code to capture image giving an input 0 to capture the image.The code seems to be running but it does not capture any image at given input.

**Following is the code**

```
  'using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Drawing.Imaging;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
   {
     public partial class mainWinForm :Form
    {            
       public mainWinForm()
       {
        InitializeComponent();
        }
      WebCam webcam;
```

//button2_Click is the button to capture the image

```
     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         int a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);//textbox to give i/p
         Console.WriteLine(a);

         try
         {


             if (a == 0)
             {
                 webcam.Start();
                 picCap.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\temp\MyImage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Wrong input");

             }

             webcam.Stop();
         }
         catch (NullReferenceException)
         {
             return;
         }             
     }

     private void mainWinForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         webcam = new WebCam();
         webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref picCap);
     }
```

//picCap_Click is the picture box where the image must get captured

```
    private void picCap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     }

}
}'
```

Exception details:
     Null Reference Exception generated

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
 HResult=-2147467261
 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 Source=WindowsFormsApplication3
 StackTrace:
   at WindowsFormsApplication3.mainWinForm.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs:line 49
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at WindowsFormsApplication3.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: yes there is a null reference exception.But I have try catched the exception... shouldn't that solve the bug?

Comment: Well, let's close this - Oswald, feel free to ask the question when you can follow the site rules. Which includes a FULL BUG REPORT. Which includes error details. If you do not enough C#, then you need to start doing some really basic learning.

Answer (score 0):

possible reson is that your webcam is null witch gives that exception: 
WebCam webcam;

try doing webcam webcam = new webcam(); also put in nessecary arguments :)

sorry my first answear but null reference is thrown  when you try to use something that is null witch web cam is becouse its not set to anything hope this helps you =)

Comment: I have already provided it in the mainWinForm_Load() function